# When does NHibernate convert Lazy Collection back to a List

Tags: nhibernate

When exactly does NHibernate convert a collection that, while the Session is open is represented as a PersistentGenericBag, but later on is converted back to the IList that I defined in my source code?

I thought it was when either the transaction was committed, or the session was disconnected. But I'm writing a unit test and no matter how many things I close, flush, commit and disconnect, my object always has a PersistentGenericBag, not a List.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not get me wrong. But do you really have mapping like this?

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public virtual List<string> MyColl { get; set; }
}
```

Because my experience says, that this will end up in exception like this:

`NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); 
setter of MyLib.MyObject ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag'1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

What I would expect inside your mapping is **IList<>**. Because exactly this will allow the NHibernate to inject its own implementation of it. Namely: `PersistentGenericBag`

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public virtual IList<string> MyColl { get; set; }
}
```

And in that case, the **answer is**: **never**. The proxy of *MyObject* provides all functionality published by IList<> while still working with property of type `PersistentGenericBag`

And when is it really populated? when firstly accessed (via getter). Inner implementation of `PersistentGenericBag` will execute sql query and load data into internal IList<>. Of course session have to be still opened and connected to MyObject

Comment: Sorry, you're right I am using IList. I'll edit my question - my mistake. Hmm, I thought it would get converted back to a .NET type at some point so e.g. when in my Controller classes (outside of the transaction boundary) I'm not working with NHibernate classes any more.

Comment: OK, this makes sense ;) As I said in my answer, it will never convert to anything else, while it is declared as *IList<>* (does not matter if implemented by PersistentGenericBag)

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right. I've just checked it in another project and even in the Controller, it's still a GenericPersistentBag. I need to go back to basics since I want to check the Count of a lazy collection outside the transaction. The whole point of my test is to make sure the collection has NOT been fetched (Assert.IsTrue(module.Components.Count == 0)) but it rightly throws a LazyInitializationException. I need to do some reading... Thanks :)